# Overwriting a Magento core class using custom module

Tags: class, magento, mod-rewrite

I encouraged to post a question here for the first time, so here it goes!

I'm trying to overwrite Magento core class for the first time; Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item located @ /app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php, but for some reason I'm not having any success as executing;

```
$object = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
var_dump(get_class($object));
```

outputs

```
string 'Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item' (length=38)
```

I created a new directory under /app/code/local/**Rage** and copied the Item.php to  /app/code/local/Rage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php renaming it to

```
class Rage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item extends Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item { ... }
```

I also made a couple of xml files. One to app/etc/modules/Rage_CatalogInventory.xml, which contains following;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Rage_CatalogInventory>
            <active>true</active>
            <codepool>local</codepool>
        </Rage_CatalogInventory>
    </modules>
</config>
```

and another to app/code/local/Rage/CatalogInventory/etc/config.xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <rage_cataloginventory>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </rage_cataloginventory>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <cataloginventory>
                <rewrite>
                    <stock_item>Rage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item</stock_item>
                </rewrite>
            </cataloginventory>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

I just can't make it work even after a couple of hours trying... This is driving me crazy. Hope you can help me out!

Many many thanks in advance.

EDIT: Fixed config.xml as Amit pointed out. It turned out that Magento had compiler in use. I figured out that could've something to this. So disabled that and cleared the includes/src -folder contents, but still nothing is happening...

Answer (score 1):

issue in config.xml and here `rage_cataloginventory` should be  `Rage_CatalogInventory` and here total config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Rage_CatalogInventory>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Rage_CatalogInventory>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <cataloginventory>
                <rewrite>
                    <stock_item>Rage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item</stock_item>
                </rewrite>
            </cataloginventory>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Amit! That's a good correction, but it didn't solve the problem itself. :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is just a guess and don´t be mad if i pointed something out that was clear to you;)
However: You did clear the config-cache, right? 
(And keep the compiler disabled for development-environment, that saves you from some trouble if you forget that you have it active.)

The xml so far looks very correct to me, so that shouldn´t be the issue.

### What to check:

- Is the module loaded at all? (See under System->Config->Advanced)?
- Is it working with any other model or just this one?
- Any log output that gives a hint as to maybe the config.xml has an error (hidden chars etc.)?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I cleared the cache several times after every tiny modification I made, and the module appears on admin side listing.. Didn't check log though. Maybe there's something, if I can find it...

I had to move on, and so I went poking core... Fortunately it _shouldn't_ matter in this case.